# Running Django Project after Cloning from Github not working?

Tags: python, django, pip

I happened to push my repo from my other computer and perhaps could have missed some files? I omitted the sqlite file since my application was just routing and serving web pages/forms. Anyways, I am attempting to `python manage.py runserver` and I keep getting an error message. It says :

```py
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alejandro/Documents/Manolo/Manolo/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path("", include("landscaping.urls"))
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alejandro/Documents/Manolo/landscaping/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/alejandro/Documents/Manolo/landscaping/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import Contact, DivErrorList
  File "/home/alejandro/Documents/Manolo/landscaping/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/phonenumber_field/formfields.py", line 1, in <module>
    import phonenumbers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers'
```

however, I already installed that package through `requirements.txt`. Is there something I'm missing?

That errror is followed up with this one.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/home/alejandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

Here's my conda env:

```py
conda list
# packages in environment at /home/alejandro/anaconda3/envs/manolo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
asgiref                   3.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
boto3                     1.16.41                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.19.41                  pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.12.8            h06a4308_0  
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.14.4                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
django                    3.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
django-localflavor        3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
django-phonenumber-field  5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
googlemaps                4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.10                     pypi_0    pypi
jmespath                  0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
openssl                   1.1.1i               h27cfd23_0  
phonenumbers              8.12.15                  pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.3.3           py37h06a4308_0  
pycparser                 2.20                     pypi_0    pypi
pynacl                    1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5                     5.12                     pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.19                  pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.9                h7579374_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-stdnum             1.14                     pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2020.4                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
requests                  2.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
s3transfer                0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                51.0.0           py37h06a4308_2  
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0  
sqlparse                  0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
telnyx                    1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
urllib3                   1.26.2                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

Is there something I'm missing or just not seeing?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my project settings from

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

don't know what that did but it worked.
to

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```